# Using an entity from a different project (vhdl) (error: 10481)

Tags: vhdl, hdl, quartus

I need to use an entity 'task3' from a different project 'lab3' the file name I need it from is also 'task3'. My current project is 'lab4'. The following is the current code for lab4.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
library lab3;
use lab3.all;

entity top is
  port(
    cin: in std_logic;
    a,b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    sum: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    cout,seg: out std_logic);
end top;

architecture behaviour of top is

  component full_adder is
    port(x,y,cin: in std_logic;
         s,cout: out std_logic);
  end component;

  signal c0,c1,c2,c3 : std_logic;
begin

  adder0: full_adder
  port map(x => a(0), y => b(0), cin => cin, s => sum(0), cout => c0);

  adder1: full_adder
  port map(x => a(1), y => b(1), cin => c0, s => sum(1), cout => c1);

  adder2: full_adder
  port map(x => a(2), y => b(2), cin => c1, s => sum(2), cout => c2);
  
  adder3: full_adder
  port map(x => a(3), y => b(3), cin => c2, s => sum(3), cout => c3);

  cout <= c3;
  
  hexto7seg: entity lab3.task3
  port map(a => sum, f => seg);

end behaviour;
```

I am trying to port map but have been unsuccessful please help me regarding this.

Comment: You didnt say what the error is. Did you even compile `task3` ?

Comment: Provide the entire error message(s) and [mcve] in your question. The line number, design library and primary unit would be of extreme interest here. Otherwise this appears to be a Quartus tool usage issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the architecture name used for task3 :

```vhdl
  hexto7seg: entity lab3.task3(arch_name)
  port map(a => sum, f => seg);
```

But with the exact error message it should be easier to find the solution.

Comment: The architecture name isn't required. There's a rule for selecting an architecture if you don't optionally provide the name. If there's only one found in the library containing the entity it's used, if there's more than one use the last one analyzed into that library is used. You can't instantiate a component with the reserved word entity that doesn't have an architecture present in the same library during analysis. It's unlikely the OP has more than one architecture.

Comment: An architecture is a secondary design unit with an entity as it's primary design unit. An architecture name must be unique within the primary unit but not within the design library containing the entity. The entity must be analyzed into the design library before it's architecture(s).

Comment: This answer should be a comment.